# Pandas melt with lists of varying size?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dict` that I want to melt into a `pandas DataFrame`.

```
d = {'a':['1','2','3'], 'b':['cat','dog','bird'], 'c':['75','23','49']}
```

When all the lists are of equal length, this method works, and I get the desired output.

```
pd.DataFrame(d).melt()
```

Out:

```
 variable   value
        0   a   1
        1   a   2
        2   a   3
        3   b   cat
        4   b   dog
        5   b   bird
        6   c   75
        7   c   23
        8   c   49
```

However, this fails when the lists are of unequal length, such as:

```
d = {'a':['1','2','3','4'], 'b':['cat','dog','bird'], 'c':['75','23','49']}
```

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **orient** method using [Dataframe.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Orient allows the keys to be used as rows in the dataframe. So after you create the dataframe you can do a simple transpose to get it in the format you desire. Then just drop the na's in the dataframe to get the final dataframe.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
d = {'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'b': ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'], 'c': ['75', '23', '49']}

e = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
e = e.T
e = e.melt()
e = e.dropna()
print(e)
```

**Output**

```
       variable value
0         a     1
1         a     2
2         a     3
3         a     4
4         b   cat
5         b   dog
6         b  bird
8         c    75
9         c    23
10        c    49
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dataframe from each column, concat them, then melt the larger dataframe and drop the na's.

```
pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(dict((tup,))) for tup in d.items()], 
    axis=1, 
    ignore_index=True
).melt().dropna()

    variable value
0          0     1
1          0     2
2          0     3
3          0     4
4          1   cat
5          1   dog
6          1  bird
8          2    75
9          2    23
10         2    49
```